# What conditions should cluster deploy mode be used instead of client?

Tags: apache-spark

The doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/submitting-applications.html

describes deploy-mode as :

```
--deploy-mode: Whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes (cluster) or locally as an external client (client) (default: client)
```

Using this diagram `fig1` as a guide (taken from http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/cluster-overview.html) :

[image]

If I kick off a Spark job :

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class com.driver \
  --master spark://MY_MASTER:7077 \
  --executor-memory 845M \
  --deploy-mode client \
  ./bin/Driver.jar
```

Then the `Driver Program` will be `MY_MASTER` as specified in `fig1` `MY_MASTER`

If instead I use `--deploy-mode cluster` then the `Driver Program` will be shared among the Worker Nodes ? If this is true then does this mean that the `Driver Program` box in `fig1` can be dropped (as it is no longer utilized) as the `SparkContext` will also be shared among the worker nodes ?

What conditions should `cluster` be used instead of `client`  ?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

No, when deploy-mode is `client`, the Driver Program is not necessarily the master node. You could run spark-submit on your laptop, and the Driver Program would run on your laptop.

On the contrary, when deploy-mode is `cluster`, then cluster manager (master node) is used to find a slave having enough available resources to execute the Driver Program. As a result, the Driver Program would run on one of the slave nodes. As its execution is delegated, you can not get the result from Driver Program, it must store its results in a file, database, etc.

- Client mode

  - Want to get a job result (dynamic analysis)
  - Easier for developing/debugging
  - Control where your Driver Program is running
  - Always up application: expose your Spark job launcher as REST service or a Web UI
- Cluster mode

  - Easier for resource allocation (let the master decide): Fire and forget
  - Monitor your Driver Program from Master Web UI like other workers
  - Stop at the end: one job is finished, allocated resources are freed

Comment: in client mode bullets points, why you say: "Easier for developping/debugging"?

Comment: So, it sounds like: client mode implies that the driver is whichever machine the spark-submit is run on? So if there's a cluster, and the deploy mode is client, the driver will be the machine you submit from, and as long as the cluster is configured properly, it'll run in parallel on the cluster? Also, it sounds like: cluster mode implies that the machine you submit on NEEDS to be the master node?

Answer (score 7):

I think this may help you understand.In the document https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html
It says " A common deployment strategy is to submit your application from a gateway machine that is physically co-located with your worker machines (e.g. Master node in a standalone EC2 cluster). In this setup, client mode is appropriate. In client mode, the driver is launched directly within the spark-submit process which acts as a client to the cluster. The input and output of the application is attached to the console. Thus, this mode is especially suitable for applications that involve the REPL (e.g. Spark shell).

Alternatively, if your application is submitted from a machine far from the worker machines (e.g. locally on your laptop), it is common to use cluster mode to minimize network latency between the drivers and the executors. Note that cluster mode is currently not supported for Mesos clusters or Python applications."

Answer (score 0):

What about HADR?

- In cluster mode, YARN restarts the driver without killing the executors.
- In client mode, YARN automatically kills all executors if your driver is killed.