# Spark: Monitoring a cluster mode application

Tags: apache-spark

Right now I'm using spark-submit to launch an application in cluster mode.  The response from the master server gives a json object with a submissionId which I use to identify the application and kill it if necessary.  However, I haven't found a simple way to retrieve the [worker rest url](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/monitoring.html#rest-api) from the master server response or the driver id (probably could web scrape the master web ui but that would be ugly).  Instead, I have to wait until the application finishes, then look up the application statistics from the history server.

Is there any way to use the driver-id to identify the worker url from an application deployed in cluster mode (usually at worker-node:4040)?

```
16/08/12 11:39:47 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://192.yyy:6066.
16/08/12 11:39:47 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submission successfully created as driver-20160812114003-0001. Polling submission state...
16/08/12 11:39:47 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request for the status of submission driver-20160812114003-0001 in spark://192.yyy:6066.
16/08/12 11:39:47 INFO RestSubmissionClient: State of driver driver-20160812114003-0001 is now RUNNING.
16/08/12 11:39:47 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Driver is running on worker worker-20160812113715-192.xxx-46215 at 192.xxx:46215.
16/08/12 11:39:47 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Server responded with CreateSubmissionResponse:
{
    "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
    "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20160812114003-0001",
    "serverSparkVersion" : "1.6.1",
    "submissionId" : "driver-20160812114003-0001",
    "success" : true
}
```

---

EDIT: Here's what a typical output looks like with log4j console output at DEBUG

Spark-submit command:

```
./apps/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master mesos://masterurl:7077 
    --verbose --class MainClass --deploy-mode cluster
    ~/path/myjar.jar args
```

Spark-submit output:

```
Using properties file: null
Parsed arguments:
  master                  mesos://masterurl:7077
  deployMode              cluster
  executorMemory          null
  executorCores           null
  totalExecutorCores      null
  propertiesFile          null
  driverMemory            null
  driverCores             null
  driverExtraClassPath    null
  driverExtraLibraryPath  null
  driverExtraJavaOptions  null
  supervise               false
  queue                   null
  numExecutors            null
  files                   null
  pyFiles                 null
  archives                null
  mainClass               MyApp
  primaryResource         file:/path/myjar.jar
  name                    MyApp
  childArgs               [args]
  jars                    null
  packages                null
  packagesExclusions      null
  repositories            null
  verbose                 true

Spark properties used, including those specified through
 --conf and those from the properties file null:



Main class:
org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient
Arguments:
file:/path/myjar.jar
MyApp
args
System properties:
SPARK_SUBMIT -> true
spark.driver.supervise -> false
spark.app.name -> MyApp
spark.jars -> file:/path/myjar.jar
spark.submit.deployMode -> cluster
spark.master -> mesos://masterurl:7077
Classpath elements:



16/08/17 13:26:49 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in mesos://masterurl:7077.
16/08/17 13:26:49 DEBUG RestSubmissionClient: Sending POST request to server at http://masterurl:7077/v1/submissions/create:
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
  "appArgs" : [ args ],
  "appResource" : "file:/path/myjar.jar",
  "clientSparkVersion" : "2.0.0",
  "environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_SCALA_VERSION" : "2.10"
  },
  "mainClass" : "SimpleSort",
  "sparkProperties" : {
    "spark.jars" : "file:/path/myjar.jar",
    "spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
    "spark.app.name" : "MyApp",
    "spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
    "spark.master" : "mesos://masterurl:7077"
  }
}
16/08/17 13:26:49 DEBUG RestSubmissionClient: Response from the server:
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "2.0.0",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20160817132658-0004",
  "success" : true
}
16/08/17 13:26:49 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submission successfully created as driver-20160817132658-0004. Polling submission state...
16/08/17 13:26:49 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request for the status of submission driver-20160817132658-0004 in mesos://masterurl:7077.
16/08/17 13:26:49 DEBUG RestSubmissionClient: Sending GET request to server at http://masterurl:7077/v1/submissions/status/driver-20160817132658-0004.
16/08/17 13:26:49 DEBUG RestSubmissionClient: Response from the server:
{
  "action" : "SubmissionStatusResponse",
  "driverState" : "RUNNING",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "2.0.0",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20160817132658-0004",
  "success" : true
}
16/08/17 13:26:49 INFO RestSubmissionClient: State of driver driver-20160817132658-0004 is now RUNNING.
16/08/17 13:26:49 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Server responded with CreateSubmissionResponse:
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "2.0.0",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20160817132658-0004",
  "success" : true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the master server's response not provide application-id?

I believe all you need is the master-URL and application-id of your application for this problem. Once you have the application-id, use the port 4040 at master-URL and append your intended endpoint to it.

For example, if your application id is application_1468141556944_1055

**To get the list of all jobs**

```
http://<master>:4040/api/v1/applications/application_1468141556944_1055/jobs
```

**To get the list of stored RDDs**

```
http://<master>:4040/api/v1/applications/application_1468141556944_1055/storage/rdd
```

However if you don't have application-id, I would probably start with following:

Set `verbose` mode (--verbose) while launching spark job to get application id on console. You can then parse for application-id in log output. The log output usually looks like:

```
16/08/12 08:50:53 INFO Client: Application report for application_1468141556944_3791 (state: RUNNING)
```

thus, application-id is *application_1468141556944_3791*

You can also find master-url and application-id through tracking URL in the log output, which looks like

```
    client token: N/A
    diagnostics: N/A
    ApplicationMaster host: 10.50.0.33
    ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
    queue: ns_debug
    start time: 1470992969127
    final status: UNDEFINED
    tracking URL: http://<master>:8088/proxy/application_1468141556944_3799/
```

These messages are at INFO log level so make sure you set `log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console` in log4j.properties file so that you can see them.

Comment: Tried --verbose, but no application id.  Log levels are already set to INFO.  Spark version 1.6.1 btw

Comment: I see these outputs on launching spark job with spark-submit on my application jar. I have got the same version. You can either try DEBUG mode (instead of INFO) or from within the code emit application-id to a local file or elsewhere using the function `SparkContext.applicationId`

Comment: That's so weird, I'll edit the question above to give my output

Comment: Are you running in client or cluster mode?

Comment: Yes I am running in cluster mode. Ah I see, you are using mesos as cluster manager and mine is yarn. I don't see submission-id in yarn anywhere and thus can't really find how to get application-id directly from submission-id. I guess I would have then tried `SparkContext.applicationId` from within the code to spit the application-id as mentioned before.

Comment: Ah, there it is.  Yeah tried on both spark standalone and master.  Unfortunately, I can't assume access to the code or use yarn so I think scraping will have to be the modus operandi.  Maybe post something on the spark mailing list.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Had to scrape the spark master web ui for an application id that's close (within the same minute & same suffix e.g. 20161010025XXX-0005 with X as wildcard), then look for the worker url in the  link tag after it.  Not pretty, reliable, or secure, but for now it'll work.  Leaving open for a bit in case someone has another approach.