# How to get driver-Id in spark submission

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, spark-streaming, spark-submit

Spark cluster information:

- Spark version: 2.2.0
- Cluster contains a master node with 2 worker nodes
- Cluster Manager Type: standalone

I submit a jar to spark cluster from one of the workers and I want to receive the driver-Id from the submission so that I can use that id for later application status checking. The problem is that I am not getting any output in the console. I use port `6066` for submission and set deploy mode to `cluster`.

By running

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --supervise --class "path/to/class" --master "spark://spark-master-headless:6066" path/to/app.jar
```

in the spark log file I am able to see the json response of the submission below, which is the exact thing that I want:

```
[INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:40,030 org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient logInfo - Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://spark-master-headless:6066.
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:41,074 org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient logInfo - Submission successfully created as driver-20180718124840-0023. Polling submission state...
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:41,077 org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient logInfo - Submitting a request for the status of submission driver-20180718124840-0023 in spark://spark-master-headless:6066.
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:41,092 org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient logInfo - State of driver driver-20180718124840-0023 is now RUNNING.
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:41,093 org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient logInfo - Driver is running on worker worker-20180707104934-<some-ip-was-here>-7078 at <some-ip-was-here>:7078.
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:41,114 org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient logInfo - Server responded with CreateSubmissionResponse:
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20180718124840-0023",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "2.2.0",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20180718124840-0023",
  "success" : true
}
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:46,572 org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend initDaemon - Started daemon with process name: 31605@spark-worker-662224983-4qpfw
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:46,580 org.apache.spark.util.SignalUtils logInfo - Registered signal handler for TERM
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:46,583 org.apache.spark.util.SignalUtils logInfo - Registered signal handler for HUP
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:46,583 org.apache.spark.util.SignalUtils logInfo - Registered signal handler for INT
 [WARN] 2018-07-18 12:48:47,293 org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader <clinit> - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:47,607 org.apache.spark.SecurityManager logInfo - Changing view acls to: root
 [INFO] 2018-07-18 12:48:47,608 org.apache.spark.SecurityManager logInfo - Changing modify acls to: root
...
```

But I want to have this information in the console so that I can direct it to a separate file than the spark logs. I assume that some messages should be get printed when the above command gets run. I even used `--verbose` mode in the command so that maybe that helps but still the output in the console is empty. 
The only thing that gets printed to console is 
`Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.` While in [this page's question section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254665/cant-find-spark-application-output?rq=1), the user is able to see more than this.

I even tried to change the Logger level in my application code but that also didn't help. (based on some ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866211/spark-monitoring-a-cluster-mode-application))

Then the question would be, how come that I am not getting any output in the console and what can I do to get the info that I want to get printed to console?
P.S. I have developed and tweaked the cluster and the jar file to a good amount that maybe I have something somewhere causing the output not to get printed. What are the possible places I can check to fix this.

### Update:

I found out that the default log4j.properties of spark has been edited. Here is the content:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=/var/log/spark.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n

# Set the default spark-shell log level to WARN. When running the spark-shell, the
# log level for this class is used to overwrite the root logger's log level, so that
# the user can have different defaults for the shell and regular Spark apps.
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=INFO

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=INFO
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR
```

I assume that this is not letting the verbose command to work. How can I change this to have get some content with `--verbose`?

Answer (score 0):

As you are running the job in cluster mode the driver can be any node in cluster, so whatever you do print/console redirect may not return to client/edge node/worker node where the console is opened.

Try submitting the apllication in client mode

Comment: This is wrong because if you submit an application through cluster mode with port 6066 the "submitter node(may be one of the workers)" gets a response in return to the submit request that it fires even if the driver gets hosted by another worker node. See [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8b7d4f842fdc90b8d1c37080bdd9b5e1d070f5c0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest/SubmitRestProtocolResponse.scala#L23) and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8b7d4f842fdc90b8d1c37080bdd9b5e1d070f5c0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest/RestSubmissionClient.scala#L77)