# Can't find spark application output

Tags: java, linux, apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I have a cluster that I can launch successfully, at least that's what appears on web UI in which I see this information

```
URL: spark://Name25:7077
REST URL: spark://Name25:6066 (cluster mode)
Alive Workers: 10
Cores in use: 192 Total, 0 Used
Memory in use: 364.0 GB Total, 0.0 B Used
Applications: 0 Running, 5 Completed
Drivers: 0 Running, 5 Completed
Status: ALIVE
```

I used submit  command to run my application, if I use it in this way

```
./bin/spark-submit --class myapp.Main --master spark://Name25:7077 --deploy-mode cluster /home/lookupjar/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/etud500.csv  /home/
```

I get this message :

> Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.
>   Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>   16/08/31 15:55:16 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://Name25:7077.
>   16/08/31 15:55:27 WARN RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark://Name25:7077.
>   Warning: Master endpoint spark://Name25:7077 was not a REST server. Falling back to legacy submission gateway instead.
>   16/08/31 15:55:28 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

and if I use it in this way :

```
./bin/spark-submit --class myapp.Main --master spark://Name25:6066 --deploy-mode cluster /home/lookupjar/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home//etud500.csv  /home/result
```

I get this message

> Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.
>   Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>   16/08/31 16:59:06 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://Name25:6066.
>   16/08/31 16:59:06 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submission successfully created as driver-20160831165906-0004. Polling submission state...
>   16/08/31 16:59:06 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request for the status of submission driver-20160831165906-0004 in spark://Name25:6066.
>   16/08/31 16:59:06 INFO RestSubmissionClient: State of driver driver-20160831165906-0004 is now RUNNING.
>   16/08/31 16:59:06 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Driver is running on worker worker-20160831143117-10.0.10.48-38917 at 10.0.10.48:38917.
>   16/08/31 16:59:06 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Server responded with CreateSubmissionResponse:
>   {
>     "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
>     "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20160831165906-0004",
>     "serverSparkVersion" : "2.0.0",
>     "submissionId" : "driver-20160831165906-0004",
>     "success" : true
>   }

I think it's a success but my application should have 3 outputs to the given path (/home/result), because I used in my code :

```
path =args [1];
rdd1.saveAsTextFile(path+"/rdd1");
rdd2.saveAsTextFile(path+"/rdd2");
rdd3.saveAsTextFile(path+"/rdd3");
```

Question 1 : Why does it ask me to use "spark://Name25:6066 " rather than "spark://Name25:7077 "? because according to spark website we use :7077

Question 2 : If it indicates success of submitting and completed applications, why don't I find the 3 output folders ?

Comment: Check whether the 7077 port is being used by any other service, and try submitting spark with `deploy-mode` as `client`. check spark master on web UI. `masterip:8080`

Comment: how can i check if 7077 is used or not?

Comment: Which OS (operating system) you are using?

Comment: i use linux on remote machines

Comment: You can try this `netstat -an | grep 7077` and try spark submit with `--deploy-mode client`.

Comment: why u suggest to use client mode?would you tell me please

Comment: when i used ""netstat...'''i got a list , this is a sample (tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.10.45:7077      :::*                        LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.10.45:7077      ::ffff:10.0.10.45:53159     ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.10.45:7077      ::ffff:10.0.10.47:42932     ESTABLISHED

Comment: Because `client` mode runs spark driver on the machine where you will submit spark and `cluster` mode can launch spark driver on any of the nodes. For more information you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807490/what-conditions-should-cluster-deploy-mode-be-used-instead-of-client).

Comment: i used client mode, i had a bunch of errors, this is the first one : ((16/08/31 19:47:49 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 545 on executor id: 16 hostname: 10.0.10.46.
16/08/31 19:47:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 244.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 532, 10.0.10.46): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: error while calling spill() on org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter@5786b516 : Aucun espace disponible sur le périphérique
 at org.apache.spark.memory.TaskMemoryManager.acquireExecutionMemory(TaskMemoryManager.java:179)

Comment: I think your application was launched, the error clearly says that one of your worker machine where a task was launched didn't have enough memory for computation. Did you check spark web Ui and I think your application ran for some time. You have to configure your memory settings.

Comment: i need to use tunel to be able to run web ui, so if i use ""ssh -L 8081:192.17.0.17:8081 name@ip""  i'll be able to see only Master UI (if i use ./sbin/start-master.sh'' , but i can't see the status of jobs on master UI

Comment: so if i use  ""ssh -L 4040:192.17.0.17:4040 name@ip"" i'll be able to see only spark UI (if i use ./bin/spark-shell'' )

Comment: what i want to say is how can i see the status of my jobs

Comment: By default 8080 port is for spark's master web UI and 8081 port is for workers ui unless you changed the configuration. Use 8080 instead of 8081 while tunneling. I can't help much on this as the problems what you are encountering are more specific to you, update your post with more specific question so that people here can help you out.

Comment: ok thank you i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Submitting using 6066 does NOT indicate that your job is successfully completed. It just sends request, the job is running in background. You have to check on spark UI for the status of job completion.

If the job is completed and your job generated output files, you can check your file using:

```
hadoop dfs -ls <path>/rdd1
```

Comment: hadoop dfs -ls <path>/rdd1   is used if we use hdfs ? because i don't use any storage system

Comment: which port should i use to check spark web UI to find jobs? because now i am using master:8081 and i can't find jobs